# Error while running the lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Can anyone clear one doubt regarding the below?

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

When i run my component keeping this in my component code, it runs perfectly fine but when i change it to :-

```
<aura:handler name="initee" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

changed init to initee, it throws me the below error while running the application:-

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Failed to initialize a component [Cannot read property 'g' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:AllApplications}
```

Why it is happening so? Please clear this doubt for me.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initee` isn't a valid handler name. The two standard supported names I know of today are `init` and `change`, for `aura:valueInit` and `aura:valueChange`, respectively. You could create a custom event and name it as such, but it would have no special meaning in the Aura framework.

Comment: ohhh...so by default i will have to use it as it is... got it! thanks a lot!!!